# How to display 1 to 10 using Python 3 file operation and loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, file

Below is my code in python 3. I am trying to print 1 to 10 using python file operations and loop.

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    file = open('text.txt', 'a+')
    file.write(str(i))
    file.write('\n')
    content = file.read()
    print(content)
    file.close()
```

Instead of printing 1 to 10 it prints nothing.
[here is a photo of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jts3Z.png).
What is wrong with this code, and is there any better way to write this code?

Comment: You would have to reset the file stream pointer to its start to `read()` something from it - it is always behind what you just wrote .. and there is not more to read there. if you would reset it to the start youwould get something like 1\n1\n2\n1\n2\n3\n etc.... write the whole file,close it, reread it and print it.

Comment: Also you would need to read/print after you close the file, otherwise the content could still be in a buffer and not yet written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you write something to the file, the file pointer is pointing at the end of the file. At this point, you are trying to read from the file but there is no data present starting from this location. Hence, you would get an empty output. However, your code will write to the file successfully (you can open the file and verify).

The best way would be to write to the file first and then read from it.

A logical solution would be to go back one line after every write and read what you have just written. Unfortunately, this can lead to a race condition and python would not allow you to do so. Interestingly, you can seek to the beginning of the file using `file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)` after every write and read the contents from start to end.